# GetCartId() showing up in echo - but not going into database

Tags: php, mysqli, sql-insert

All other information is going into the database
the cart id is coming up in echo (30+ numbers)
but no matter how I configure the query it comes up as 0 in the database

```
echo GetCartId();

mysqli_query($con,"insert into cart(product,name,image,price,cookieId) values('limited edition','$heading','$art',60,'".GetCartId()."')");
```

Comment: Whats the columns data type for `cookieId`?

Comment: did you try assisgning cartId to a local variable and then pass it ?

Comment: int(111) thanks so much - there is a letter in the id - so should I change it to varchar

Comment: Yeah if it's not an int

Comment: I have changed it to varchar and it went into the cart - but now it wont come up on the checkout page as I have discovered I have different cart ids depending on where in the website I am clicking the buy button

Comment: would you please please use prepared queries? (I also would suggest pdo, but that's just my preference). Also, there might be some weird behaviour with strings and numbers in sqlite, be sure to only store numbers in numeric columns - that is, without the `''` quotes.